# Is it less performant to use multiple websocket connections instead of one on the client

Tags: websocket

I am currently building a bot. Currently, I have 102 socket connections opened. I have found a way to start a multiplex socket to connect to different streams of events at the same time. Oh and also the server is not mine. Will the performance be better doing so? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each open socket requires memory on both client and server and requires processing to open the socket and to send keep-alives.  Further, all sockets coming from client share the same server bandwidth.  All sockets from a given client share the same client bandwidth.

If you're at a scale thousands or tens of thousands of clients or more all connecting to one server, then you will definitely want to limit your clients to as few socket.io connections per client as possible.  This will enhance your server scalability (with less connection and keep-alive overhead) and reduce server memory usage.  And, because they all share the same client and server bandwidth, it should not reduce your processing speed in any way.

If you have 102 sockets opened per client, then you really want to reduce that right away unless you're only going to have a small number of clients ever connected at once.

> Will the performance be better doing so?

Reducing the number of socket.io connections that each client has will increase server scalability.  It may improve performance or the performance impact may be imperceptible.  That depends upon a lot of factors (such as how much spare, unused CPU and bandwidth your server has).  At the very minimum, the connection time will be reduced as you just have to establish one connection instead of many.  It is generally a good thing to reduce the number of socket.io connections each client has.